# Connect DB In laravel 5

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am trying to learn laravel.I got a problem with db connection.i did everything to connect set host name,user,db and password also but still got error and not able to connect with my DB

Error:

```
FatalErrorException in MainModel.php line 17: Class 'App\DB' not found
```

Db Configuration:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'myblog'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to import `DB` into your file - see https://laravel.io/index.php/forum/11-29-2015-class-appdb-not-found for an example (third Google result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you put the DB connection values in the wrong place. This is how the env function works env($name, $defaultValue)

Basically you're telling env to return 'root' as username, but only if DB_USERNAME doesn't exists. Looking at the error you posted in your comments, it seems that you're trying to connect as homestead, which is usually the default value in your .env file.

If you have a .env file in your root folder, then that's where you should put your values.

Comment: thank buddy...its working now

Comment: No problem at all :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to import DB class

```
  use DB;
```

Comment: now got PDOException in Connector.php line 47: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: it seems that your username and password are wrong. double check your .env file

Comment: @Nic let me update my question with my DB configuration

Comment: Update database detail in .env file

Comment: 'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''), password is empty, but in your DB (using password: YES), set your password to .env file

Comment: Otherwise remove env method and direct use database  detail directly in database.php config file

Comment: @Rishi thanks alot for answer..working.i just remove env extension